# Error: Localhost does not exist when deploying asp.net application using jenkins

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, jenkins, localhost

I am using Jenkins 4.26.2, I have configured a web site on my localhost at default port 80.
When I build the application It creates deployment package successfully. But gives error on installing that package to IIS.

> Error: (5/25/2017 1:07:21 AM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer. Error: Site 'localhost' does not
>   exist.

here are the commands:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\EMR\EMR.WEB\emr.web.csproj" /T:Build;Package /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:OutputPath="obj\DEBUG" /p:DeployIisAppPath="/localhost" /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0


"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\EMR\EMR.WEB\obj\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\emr.web_Package\emr.web.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=localhost -allowUntrusted=true
```

Comment: Is Jenkins and IIS are in same server.

Comment: Yes, Jenkins and IIS are on same machine.

Comment: Try updating the /p:DeployIisAppPath="/localhost" this value with the IIS site name by looking into IIS Manager. From the error message it is connecting to localhost but it is saying Site 'localhost' does not exit.

Comment: If I try it like this /p:DeployIisAppPath="http://192.168.10.2:8085" it give following error.
Error: (5/25/2017 10:16:29 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: Site 'http:' does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide me the screenshot of the IIS Manager with Sites expanded.

Comment: Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site '192.168.10.2:8085' does not exist.

Comment: http://jmp.sh/PURTex2

@Suresh Screenshot link.

Comment: /p:DeployIisAppPath="EMR/emr"; try with this and let provide me the log if any error occurs

Comment: Here is the error log, when I change to "EMR/emr"

Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost") using the specified process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.

Comment: Did you verified that the mentioned service is running or not.

Comment: I am using windows 10, Web Deployment Agent Service is not there, I have tried to figure out how to install it there. But could not find a solution.